# drag and drop firefox ghost image position

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a drag and drop game and it works fine in all browsers except Firefox. In Firefox the ghost image that appears when an item is dragged is positioned far away from the cursor. The ghost image is still visible on the page but very far from the cursor.

I'm not able to provide a screenshot but here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cawitofani/edit?html,css,js,output) of the expected behavior.

Is there any kind of CSS that could be messing with the drag and drop behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to drag n drop, however, check your jsbin console.  I'm getting the following error:

```
"error"
"@cawitofani.js:40:3
k</b.render/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.39.11.min.js:1:13924
j</a.use/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.39.11.min.js:1:10855
"
```

Comment: I should clarify, my question is only referring to the translucent image that appears when you are dragging an image. In the jsbin you should see a translucent image of the dragged object close to the cursor. However, in my application the translucent image is appearing far away from the cursor in firefox.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and it's pretty much where I click the image to drag it.

Try CTRL-R to refresh your cache, then hit CTRL-0 (zero) to make sure your page hasn't been resized.